# PHP - how to print newline?

Tags: php, xml

I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm trying to print a newline (`\n`) after each row of my XML.

```
$xml = '<items>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $xml = $xml.'<product>';
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $xml = $xml . "<$key>$val </$key>";
        }
        $xml = $xml . '</product>';
        PHP_EOL;
    }
    $xml = $xml . '</items>';
```

But it gives me an output like this:

```
1 Coca-cola Can 5 30 100 pcs 2 Sprite 5 50 10 pcs 3 Fanta 5 100 20 pcs
```

I want an output like:

```
1 Coca-cola Can 5 30 100 pcs
2 Sprite 5 50 10 pcs
3 Fanta 5 100 20 pcs
```

I have tried many variations and have seen many answers, but none worked for me. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you trying to do? Is this for displaying on a website?

Comment: no, for my assignment. i used "</br>" , "\n", but none work. i just want to print a new line after every product information. thanks.

Comment: Whats the assigment?

Comment: `\n` or `PHP_EOL` doesn't print a new line on screen. Look at your HTML source and you'll see the line breaks there. If you want to see it "on screen", use HTML `<br>` or `<p>` tags.

Comment: i have to fetch information from phpmyadmin database and show it using XML

Comment: Parse the XML and output in the elements you want it in.. `ol`.

Comment: Btw, `$xml .= 'a';` is a shorthand for `$xml = $xml . 'a';`.

Comment: i ticked the helpful answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
        $xml = $xml.'</product>';
        PHP_EOL;
```

You have to concatenate that PHP_EOL, like this:

```
        $xml = $xml . '</product>' . PHP_EOL;
```

But, if you want to show the new line on the screen, then use `<br>`:

```
$xml = $xml . '</product>' . '<br>';
```

Comment: glad to help you! please check this answer as the accepted one  :)

Answer (score 2):

To get newline character use `\n`. But for this escape sequence you need to use double quotes:

```
echo "new\nline";
```

will output

```
new
line
```

while

```
echo 'new\nline`;
```

would literaly output `new\nline` string. If you prefer single quotes for you string then you do something like:

```
echo 'new' . "\n" . 'line';
```

Comment: Will output a new line in HTML source (or if written to a file), not on screen.

Comment: `not on screen`. aha. How come you got 60K rep and still post such nonsense? Have you read and understood OP's question? Do you see any HTML in there?

Comment: *Facepalm* - You don't have to insult me. Btw,`\n` **WILL NOT** post new lines on screen. `<br>` or `<p>` will. I've enough experience in PHP to back that with. `echo "new\nline";` produces `new line` in **one line**, while **viewing HTML source** for that same line of code, reveals it in two lines. What am I not grasping here?

Comment: For the *edited* part of your comment, yes I have. OP: *"i'm trying to **print** a newline"*.

Comment: `WILL NOT post new lines on screen` - of course it will. But you seem to not to understand basics here - PHP is regular programming language and using it for web is just one case. Saying that `print` means sending stuff in HTML is just a proof you do not really know what you talk about. It's funny that you waste time for the comments instead of trying and fixing your knowledge. Some hints for you then: run my code in shell. And another hint. For trying with your beloved browser - echo `<pre>` first. Magic! "it's not on screen" but it's there. See now?

Comment: well, I don't see a green tick next to your answer. You either didn't solve this, or the OP doesn't know what to do with it, or just didn't see the answers. But yeah... I suggest you create a file of your own and do `<?php echo "new\nline";` just for kicks. If the OP wants to "print", this means to me and in the common world of viewing/printing/etc. is a visual representation. You most likely don't like me and that's ok with me, I don't expect you to. However, you don't have to show disrespect. I know enough about this but hey... if you want magic, I'll get a bunny and a top hat.

Comment: [*But, if you want to show the new line on the screen, then use <br>*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36377121/) - OP's response: [*" thanks, this helped :D – Sabah 49 mins ago"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377033/php-how-to-print-newline/36377122?noredirect=1#comment60371976_36377121) - and I posted [this comment to the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377033/php-how-to-print-newline/36377122?noredirect=1#comment60372856_36377033) for any of the answers given.

Comment: See my previous comment. Do the tests I mentioned. Further discussion is pretty much pointless.